# How to limit number of replica of a service for a specific node?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Use case :

I have 2 nodes, a machineA with 1gb of RAM and a machineB with 4 gb of ram.

I deploy a service with 5 réplicas of Java container which use 1 gb of ram.

There will 1 be one Java container on machineA and 4 Java container on machine B.

If i shutdown machineB how can i prevent machineA to launch 4 Java ?

The machine doesn't hava enough RAM to launch these container and instead of improve availability it will decrease it.

Comment: I am not sure, but such schedueling strategies are build into swarm, so you don't have to configure them. https://docs.docker.com/swarm/scheduler/strategy/#spread-strategy-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is not there as of now. There is a open issue for the same

https://github.com/docker/swarm/issues/1734

What you should do is add constraints of memory requirements. So if you add `500MB` per container then that will prevent such a situation

```
docker service create --name nginx --reserve-memory 500Mb --replicas 3 nginx
```

Comment: Will this option reserve 500 MB for each of the Nginx so 1,5Gb or for the set of Nginx ?

Comment: Yes. So if a machine has 1GB memory free then only 2 containers can get scheduled